# Fixing out of sync warning in Argo CD - Unable to ignore the optional `preserveUnknownFields` field

Tags: kubernetes, jsonpath, argocd, linkerd, jsonpointer

Argo CD shows two items from linkerd (installed by Helm) are being out of sync. The warnings are caused by the optional `preserveUnknownFields: false` in the `spec` section:

trafficsplits.split.smi-spec.io
[image]

[image]

serviceprofiles.linkerd.io

[image]

[image]

But I'm not able to figure out how to ignore the difference using `ignoreDifferences` in the `Application` manifest. The `/spec/preserveUnknownFields` json path isn't working. Is it because the field preserveUnknownFields is not present in the left version?

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: linkerd
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  destination:
    namespace: linkerd
    server: https://kubernetes.default.svc
  project: default
  source:
    chart: linkerd2
    repoURL: https://helm.linkerd.io/stable
    targetRevision: 2.10.1
 syncPolicy:
    automated: {}
  ignoreDifferences:
     - group: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1
       name: trafficsplits.split.smi-spec.io
       kind: CustomResourceDefinition
       jsonPointers:
         - /spec/preserveUnknownFields
     - group: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1
       name: trafficsplits.split.smi-spec.io
       kind: CustomResourceDefinition
       jsonPointers:
         - /spec/preserveUnknownFields
```

Comment: Hello @RedGiant, did the solution of vikas027 help you?

Comment: Yes, I just tried it. it works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-cd/user-guide/diffing/#application-level-configuration), I think you have to use `apiextensions.k8s.io` not `apiextensions.k8s.io/v1`.